# Response time graph and aggregate report does match

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am running Jemter using non-guie mode and then generating the graphs by loading the jtl file. I find that the max and average and average values in graph and aggregate table do not match always. But during some run, the values match exactly.

[image: Response time Graph]

[image: Aggregate report]

As it is evident from the graph and aggregate report the values for HTTP Request1 is matching and for Request2 are not matching at all. The max value for Request2  is shown as 600+ms while the graph for request2 does not have a value more than 5oms.

Any suggestion are having this corrected or any reason for this strange behavior will be very helpful

Comment: You have to trust to the aggregate table or better to jtl file itself (and build a graph from there with some other ways). Every graph has additional options in "settings" tab (group settings and limit number of points to draw) which can have a big impact on the picture.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Are you aware of any details on how response graph is plotted, like if the average in few seconds is plotted or etc?

Comment: By default, it is grouping by 1000 ms. So your test has a duration of 1401 seconds. during the test were executed 35.1 req/s in average. If during one second were executed 34 requests with response time 6ms and one with 609 ms - graph will draw point on (34 * 6 + 609)/35 = 23 ms. Something like that. The only one reason why request 1 has spikes cuz during these 2 periods on the graph were executed very few requests. (system does not respond?)